# Android webview settings, disable some things

Tags: android, controls, webview, zooming

I am using `myWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);` to set zoom controls on my webview.

I realize this enables a variety of zoom controls that are different on every phone/device.

For aesthetic purposes I would like to specifically turn on and turn off some features, for instance, the +/- zoom buttons that appear in the corner

These don't fit in my layout.

Pinch to zoom? OK
Double tap to zoom? OK
actual zoom buttons? No thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible with the provided methods. There's a `setDisplayZoomControls()`, but that only works for API11+.

A previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview) suggests a possible approach, though it looks somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: I'm developing for a tablet, so its 3.0+  I'm really excited about that

Answer (score 0):

You should use

.getZoomButtonsController()

on your getSettings to update those.

You can find more information about the possible settings that you can change on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.html