# About WebView: How to disable the zoom Control buttons but still supporting zoom?

Tags: android, webview

Is there any way to solve this? i don't want wo show the zoom control buttons in my webview,but it still supporting the zoom controls with mutiTouch.

thanks for your attention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [enable/disable zoom in Android WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview)

Answer (score -1):

If you want have zoom in/out without zoom controls then use the below code(copied from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130931/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/02/webview-with-zoomcontrols-in-android.html))

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private WebView myWebView;
  private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS =
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
Gravity.BOTTOM);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = myWebView.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.almondmendoza.com");
  }
}
```