# Non-visible zoom controls in WebView

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I want pinch-to-zoom in WebView but I dont want it to have the integrated control (the little zoom in and zoom out buttons) all I want is the pinch to zoom.
I tried this and it didn't work:

```
wv1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
wv1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Any ideas would be great!

p.s. I'm using API Version 8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On **API 11 or greater**, you can use:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

From API 11,

```
public void setDisplayZoomControls (boolean enabled)
```

Sets whether the on screen zoom buttons are used. A combination of built in zoom controls enabled and on screen zoom controls disabled allows for pinch to zoom to work without the on screen controls

Look at [enable/disable zoom in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview).

Comment: I get this error: **The method setDisplayZoomControls(boolean) is undefined for the type WebSettings**

Comment: Which API version you are using?

Comment: Its Froyo, So its API version 8.

Comment: ok, take a look at question link I mentioned in my answer, I think you can find your solution there.

Comment: Thanks, It's a little more complicated than I thought but it should work :D

Comment: I am developing an android application for API level 9 and above, so how can i get above solution in my case?

Comment: Don't you mean: webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); ?

Comment: @LoungeKatt, that is definitely what he means. Ah, lexdysia. It gets the best of us.