# Disable Double Tap Zoom/Unzoom on a webview

Tags: android, webview, zooming

On Android, I'm am using a webview to display a chart designed by the API flot.

I'm using this code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.graphique);

    // Get a reference to the declared WebView holder
    WebView webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    // Get the settings
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    // Enable Javascript for interaction
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Make the zoom controls visible
    //webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Allow for touching selecting/deselecting data series
    webview.requestFocusFromTouch();

    // Set the client
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.setBackgroundColor(0);

    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    // Load the URL
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/graph.html");
```

The graph is displayed correctly and fills the entire webview even if the width and height are not the same at start (thanks to setLoadWithOverviewMode(true) and setUseWideViewPort(true)).

But the user can still zoom and unzoom the graph by double tapping on it.

I want to prevent this action, I tried to put my webview to clickable=false, focusable=false and focusableintouchmode=false but it doesn't work.

I tried this also :

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

But it doesn't work. Do you have any clue ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview

Comment: Please have a try on my answer from a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21472048/510577

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try to set

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

and deal with scale manually to fit the width..

Comment: I think this works but how to scale manually the width ? My graph width and height cannot be defined, can I scale it from my code directly ?