# disable double tap zoom in webview android

Tags: android, webview

This question is already having solutions in stackoverflow, but sorry guys Im not able to solve the issue with my code.please help me to disable double tap or any other zooming activities...

User_reg.java

```
package com.example.samworkshops;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class User_reg extends Activity {
 private WebView webView;
 final Activity activity = this;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);                                                         
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        webView.setInitialScale(90);

        webView.loadUrl("http://app.samworkshops.org/User_Reg.aspx");

        webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_user_reg);
            }
        });

        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("black"));


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");


                    builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('Image3').style.visibility= 'hidden';");
                    builder.append("javascript:document.getElementById('Image3').style.display   = 'none'  ;");
view.loadUrl(builder.toString());

                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SystemClock.sleep(2000);

            }


        });

    }

}
```

Comment: go to this :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018714/disable-double-tap-zoom-unzoom-on-a-webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018714/disable-double-tap-zoom-unzoom-on-a-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this controls it will help:

```
webView .getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView .getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webView .getSettings().setSupportZoom (false);
```