# How to remove zoom buttons on Android webview?

Tags: android, zooming, android-webview

Is it possible to remove the zoom buttons [image]? Its showing when I zooming the WebView. I need zoom control without these buttons. I'm using android 2.3.

I used below code,

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
        getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
final View zoom = webview.getZoomControls();
mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: can we discuss here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal

Comment: @bharath can u help me fr [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777116/enable-zoom-for-all-pages-of-an-android-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally my answer is, Its not possible to hide/remove these button's on `WebView` in Android 2.3.

Answer (score 30):

```
getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

use the above line of code to remove the zoom buttons.

On API >= 11, you can use:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

**Updated:::** If you want have zoom in/out without zoom controls then use the below code(copied from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130931/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/02/webview-with-zoomcontrols-in-android.html))

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private WebView myWebView;
  private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS =
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
Gravity.BOTTOM);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = myWebView.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.almondmendoza.com");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Change this on your AndroidManifest:

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

to this:

```
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
```

than use this in your web view settings:

```
getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to disable only zoom controls use this:
`webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);`

Answer (score 3):

Follow this code. It will help you.

Main.java

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1) ;
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: At best, this would *enable* the zoom controls.

Comment: change boolean value to false

Answer (score 3):

Just add this line:

```
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: The guy asked about Android 2.3, this is not possible with 2.3

Answer (score 1):

zoom buttons can be removed by implementing your own custom webview, and using reflection to get the built in zoom controls and making them invisible for API below 11 (Honeycomb). The code is as thus works for all APIs upto android nougat;

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView{

    private ZoomButtonsController zoom_controll = null;

    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.webViewStyle);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initWebSettings();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initWebSettings() {
        WebSettings webSettings = getSettings();

        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
            webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        } else {
            try {
                Class webview = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView");
                Method method = webview.getMethod("getZoomButtonsController");
                zoom_controll = (ZoomButtonsController) method.invoke(this, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(zoom_controll != null)
            zoom_controll.getZoomControls().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN) {
    if (multiTouchZoom && !buttonsZoom) {
        if (ev.getPointerCount() > 1) {
            getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        } else {
            getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        }
    }
}

if (!multiTouchZoom && buttonsZoom) {
    if (getPointerCount(ev) > 1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your case `multiTouchZoom` is true and `buttonsZoom` is false.

I found it here [enable/disable zoom in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview) and it's worked for me.

Comment: what are multiTouchZoom and buttonsZoom variables?

Comment: @jayellos replace them with your boolean values. If you want multitouch zoom, replace `multiTouchZoom` with true. If you need to display zoom buttons, replace `buttonsZoom` with true. Otherwise, replace with false.