# Enable zoom for all pages of an android application

Tags: android, html, cordova, zooming

i have created an android app using phone-gap[Android].

Here i am able to zoom my first .html page of application, but when ever i moving/redirecting to a page by clicking the anchortag/button of my first .html page there i am unable to zoom the second .html page

i have added below things in my .java

```
WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

and i have also added the following in all my .html pages.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=6, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

so here my question is: how to enable the zooming effect

any help will be appriciated.......

Comment: @ Subrat, I didn't use phonegap. But you can try like this, `webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

Comment: @bharath i have already tried this one, as given above.........

Comment: i have jst updated the phone gap and everything started working fine......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just updated the Phonegap to Cordova1.9.0 and everything started working fine.