# setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()) Remove Buttons

Tags: android, webview

How I can remove buttons (zoom in / out), the search bar, ie remove all buttons on the **map**.

Is there any way to remove the input buttons etc. ? I think yes, but with javascript

Map :

```
 <WebView
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:clickable="true"></WebView>
```

How call ?

```
 webView = (WebView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Note : I load a url map

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766669/how-to-remove-zoom-buttons-on-android-webview

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
webView.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

if the other way didn't work, use `WebSettings`

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

[`setBuildInZoomControls`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean))

> Sets whether the WebView should use its built-in zoom mechanisms. The built-in zoom mechanisms comprise on-screen zoom controls, which are displayed over the WebView's content, and the use of a pinch gesture to control zooming. Whether or not these on-screen controls are displayed can be set with setDisplayZoomControls(boolean). The default is false.

If you know how to do with `JavaScript` try it by your own doing this :

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,"<script> Here the script  </script>","text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Comment: zoom, + indicator ? + input search ? + mapstate(change color map) ?

Comment: What do you mean? @warped2.0

Comment: Show this url https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=zeU8M-wjwMo0.kbwrypXJeOM8 I need hide all elements

Comment: But zoom was removed?

Comment: @warped2.0 Solved your problem or shall I update the answer?

Comment: Yes with the before link

Comment: @warped2.0 what link?

Comment: Oh okay, so if you solved your problem and my answer helped to you feel free to mark it as a correct :)