# NativeScript: How do I disable zoom controls in WebView?

Tags: webview, nativescript

I found the way to enable/disable zoom controls in Android WebView  from following question.

[How to remove zoom buttons on Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766669/how-to-remove-zoom-buttons-on-android-webview)

I'm using NativeScript and I don't see similar method in NativeScript WebView. Is there any way I can access the methods of Android WebView from NativeScript? Or, is there any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get hold of the actual android trough the `android` property of your WebView. So you can probably use something like that in the loaded event:

```
var webView = page.getViewById("webViewID");
if(webView.android) { // in IOS android will be undefined
  webView.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
}
```

Comment: I've tried that before and didn't work. I though I did wrong and your answer encourage me to try again. Now it's working after putting that code in loadStarted event of WebView. Thanks.

Comment: but how can i get page reference in angular

Comment: How to just hide the buttons only while keeping the pinch to zoom enabled?

Comment: Anyone know how can I get `page` in {N}-Vue ?  it turns out `ReferenceError: page is not defined`

Answer (score 11):

Just add this meta tag to header of your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 5):

In NS + Angular:

```
import { WebView, LoadEventData } from "ui/web-view";
...
//Get the element ref from the view #webView
@ViewChild("webView") webView: ElementRef;  
...
//Get the real object type casted
let webview: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement; 
if(webview.android) {
    webview.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
}
```