# NativeScript: Way to disable zoom controls for iOS WebView?

Tags: ios, webview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to figure out a way to prevent users from zooming in and out on an iOS WebView (tns-ios 3.4.1) via pinch gestures & double tapping, essentially disabling all scaling like the html meta tag used to do before apple went to letting the user decide if he wants to zoom with iOS 10 and above. 
I found a solution for android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808087/nativescript-how-do-i-disble-zoom-controls-in-webview/), for iOS it doesn't appear to be as trivial though.

I am pretty new to the platform, is this currently possible at all? I found that NS recently switched from UIWebView to WKWebView, can we use the [allowsMagnification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414983-allowsmagnification) property somehow from NativeScript (*with angular)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will not be able to use `allowsMagnification`. You will have extend  to your own version of WebView component in order to update meta configuration to stop zooming.

**Update:**

The default viewport being injected from {N} core module (v5.x) has to be modified in order to disable zoom, here is how it done.

```
import { WebView } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/web-view';

declare var WKUserScript, WKUserScriptInjectionTime, WKUserContentController, WKWebViewConfiguration, WKWebView, CGRectZero;

(<any>WebView.prototype).createNativeView = function () {
    const jScript = `var meta = document.createElement('meta'); 
    meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
    meta.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);`;
    const wkUScript = WKUserScript.alloc().initWithSourceInjectionTimeForMainFrameOnly(jScript, WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
    const wkUController = WKUserContentController.new();
    wkUController.addUserScript(wkUScript);
    const configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration.new();
    configuration.userContentController = wkUController;
    configuration.preferences.setValueForKey(
        true,
        "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"
    );
    return new WKWebView({
        frame: CGRectZero,
        configuration: configuration
    });
};
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=OdkchY&v=1)

Comment: Someone mentions having done this in a Nativescript Issues thread about disabling zooming: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5443#issuecomment-374497857

Not sure it this works, but is this the kind of thing you're talking about?

Comment: Manoj, can your solution be done in plain JS? I'm not exactly sure what's going on there, but your code looks like the best candidate for this problem.

Comment: Just remove the typings from code, then it's all just JS.

Comment: There is a working Playground sample above, I'm not sure if have checked it.

Comment: No idea where you found this solution but it works!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to from NS 3.3 - 4.1

Get your #webview reference and then setup these properties for ios and android to fix the view zooming.

```
let webView: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;
webView.on(WebView.loadStartedEvent, function (args: LoadEventData) {               
    if (webView.android) {
        webView.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.android.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    } else {
        webView.ios.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        webView.ios.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
        webView.ios.scalesPageToFit = false;
        webView.ios.scrollView.bounces = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, how would this look like if using nativescript-vue?

Comment: I wasn't able to disable zooming on iOS with this configuration. Anyone know if this issue has made any progress elsewhere?

Comment: Confirmed that this doesn't work on iOS.