# Android Webview initial zoom out

Tags: java, android, webview, zooming

I'm using a webview in my android app, at the moment when the app is started the website is zoomed in quite a lot, i want it to be zoomed out to fit the width of the screen. I currently have this in my activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shop);
    WebView webview;
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: Vote my answer below. Set default zoom out = webview.setInitialScale(-1);

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

This will cause the webview to be zoomed out initially.

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

The Webview will have a normal viewport (like desktop browser), when false the webview will have a viewport constrained to it's own dimensions.

**EDIT**: With the introduction of "Chrome web view" in Android KitKat, this code might not work.

Comment: I used this with `wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);` per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7903262/536986) to default my view to zoomed out and to be able to pinch-to-zoom.

Comment: Refer this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=92841 in .xml file you should set android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_height="match_parent" for webview. If you set android:layout_height="wrap_content", webview doesn't  auto zoom out in android 4.4

Answer (score 19):

This zooms out so that the content (an SVG in my case) fits on the screen but does not make unnecessary space.

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
```

Comment: The initial scale is working for me. The 2nd page is zoomed out by default now.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
    webView.setInitialScale(50);
    webPlanSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webPlanSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: setDefaultZoom() is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

```
    //This the the enabling of the zoom controls 
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    //This will zoom out the WebView
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
```

Comment: this what worked with me
without need last line of code

Answer (score 3):

For Kit Kat and later devices you need to set the viewport meta tag in the headers of the HTML page loaded by your WebView in order to prevent the default zoom in behavior.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the [webSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) class to set the zoom level...

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set WebView settings like:

```
webView.settings.run {
    builtInZoomControls = true
    //hide +- zoom buttons
    displayZoomControls = false 
    //zooms out the content to fit on screen by width
    loadWithOverviewMode = true 
    //when page contains the viewport meta tag
    useWideViewPort = true 
}
```

But consider that zoom settings above, work only for WebView first run.

If you want to full **zoom out every time you load a URL** in WebView (I faced this case), use zoomBy like this

```
webView.loadUrl(url)
webView.zoomBy(0.02f)
```

Comment: By adding the code, i can able to scroll the view hence the zoom out is not applied

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset the zoom level to its initial state every time a webpage loads (whether it's a refresh or a new page), you can implement the following code within the **onPageFinished** method. This will set the zoom to the default state:

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        view?.post {
            view.zoomBy(0.0101f) // Ensure the value is slightly greater than 0.01
        }
    }
```

This approach ensures that the zoom is effectively reset. Special thanks to [George Vortelinos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8575276/george-vortelinos) for providing the initial solution.