# App made with android studio exceeds phone width

Tags: android, android-studio

I have made an app for my blog. Blog looks fine while using a browser but with app it exceeds screen width.
[This is my blog](https://arianaraa.blogspot.com/)

[This is what i see from my browser (opera, yandex etc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6OUX.png)
[And the result using the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRwPO.png)

```xml
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="WebViewLayout" />
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And the main activity xml

Comment: Looks like your blog doesn't have a mobile/small screen layout. The WebView is just showing what the HTML and CSS code of your blog tell it. Also you can't compare a wide desktop view with a mobile view. You can simulate a mobile view on your desktop and thus adapt your blog https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mobile-emulator/

Comment: I am comparing mobile browsers not desktop

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add these two lines in my java file.
Thanks  [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830304/19615939)

```html
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
```