# Android WebView disable automatic Zoom

Tags: android, webview

is there a possibility to disable the automatic zoom when i'am clicking an input field in my Webview ?

I'd tryed with some meta tags:

`user-scalable=no;initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1`

But that doesent work.
The Zoom is disabled if i put a meta-tag `width` in there. But is there a possibility without this meta tag ? Just with the Java code ?
I'd tryed:

`webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);`

(Better, but not correct)

`webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [enable/disable zoom in Android WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this code:

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Now the zoom is fixed, but the WebView ist to large. Is there a possibility without the setting "width" ?