# Android WebView disable PinchZoom but keep Controlls

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I've an android-app (Android SDK 10) with a WebView. On that WebView I have to use elements with a fixed position. Now I know, that there are Problems with fixed Elements, but with this Code in the HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport"
  content="width=100%; 
  initial-scale=1;
  maximum-scale=1;
  minimum-scale=1; 
  user-scalable=no;">
```

And this for the Webview:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("path/to.html");
```

I am able to zoom when using the zoomcontrolls. Multitouch- and pinchzoom distorts the page however.

Is there a possibility to disable pich- and multitouchzoom but keep the zoom-controlls working?

---

With the suggestions of Vikalp Patel I've come to this solution:

```
CustomWebView mWebView = (CustomWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.loadUrl("path/to.html");
```

CustomWebView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.webkit.WebView#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
            this.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            this.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        } else {
            this.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            this.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Implementation in layout.xml

```
<package.path.CustomWebView
   ...
 />
```

Hope, that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the source code for WebView and I concluded that there is no elegant way to accomplish what you are asking.

What I ended up doing was subclassing WebView and overriding `OnTouchEvent`

. In `OnTouchEvent` for `ACTION_DOWN`, I check how many pointers there are using `MotionEvent.getPointerCount()`. If there is more than one pointer, I call `setSupportZoom(false)`, otherwise I call `setSupportZoom(true)`. I then call the `super.OnTouchEvent()`.

This will effectively disable zooming when scrolling (thus disabling the zoom controls) and enable zooming when the user is about to pinch zoom. Not a nice way of doing it, but it has worked well for me so far.

Note that `getPointerCount()` was introduced in 2.1 so you'll have to do some extra stuff if you support 1.6.

Comment: You can find many solutions regarding these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out. I've edited my Post with the solution i made from your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to the following code

WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("path/to.html");
```