# How can I stop zoom in webpage of webview in android for HTC

Tags: android, webview, zooming, htc-android

How can I stop zoom in webpage of webview in android for HTC mobiles when clicking in input text . Any suggestions will be appreciated .

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview

Comment: webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN ||
        ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_3_DOWN) {
    if (multiTouchZoom && !buttonsZoom) {
        if (getPointerCount(ev) > 1) {
            getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        } else {
            getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        }
    }
}

if (!multiTouchZoom && buttonsZoom) {
    if (getPointerCount(ev) > 1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already checked out that. But the code is not working in HTC mobiles. As i think HTC has already did certain customizations to web view so that our zoom options don't work over there.

Comment: webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelpWebView extends WebView {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private AtomicBoolean mPreventAction = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private AtomicLong mPreventActionTime = new AtomicLong(0);

public HelpWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public HelpWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public HelpWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public HelpWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, boolean privateBrowsing) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle, privateBrowsing);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int index = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    int pointId = event.getPointerId(index);

    // just use one(first) finger, prevent double tap with two and more fingers
    if (pointId == 0){
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (mPreventAction.get()){
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - mPreventActionTime.get() > ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout()){
                mPreventAction.set(false);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        mPreventAction.set(true);
        mPreventActionTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        mPreventAction.set(true);
        mPreventActionTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Even the code above also tested but that is of no use

Answer (score 0):

Finally, what i have observed with HTC is It has customized android OS and our webview settings never work there. Though i have customized webview there is no use. And i worked out on my issue in other way.

It only has FAR,CLOSE,MEDIUM settings in webview zoom.that has already set.But we can change them at setting of mobile.Apart from that we can't change anything.