# Web View double tap

Tags: android, webview, zooming, pinchzoom

I have a layout which consist of formulas,its basically html codes displayed in **webview**. I made the `webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`
But I dont want the zoom buttons, just the pinch zoom or better double tap with pinch zoom.

There are questions on SO like:-
[enable/disable zoom in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview)

But,they are not helpful as they are trying to support till honeyComb. I just want **double tab zoom without the zoom controls**. How can that be achieved ?